# Adafruit moto and stage table

Tags: power-supply, voltage, motor, stepper-motor, amperage

I have an adafruit motor with a power supply voltage of 15v (Max) and a output current of 1.2v (ave)/3.2v (peak). I want to use it with a stage table that has two stepper motors. One motor uses 0.6amps and the other is 0.8 amps and the stage table has a driving voltage of 24v DC. Can i safely use these two things together?

Comment: I'm confused. You want to know if you can use your 15 V motor in some combination with two other motors? What do you mean by output current from this 15 V motor and, did you mean 1.2 A (ave)/3.2 A (peak)? (Instead of V)

Comment: And what do you mean "use these things together". What things? Also what do you mean that the stage table has a driving voltage of 24V DC?

Comment: @Matt I did mean 1.2A and 3.2A 
here are the specification of the stage table 
Specification:
Working area: 300mm x 200mm ;     Driving voltage:24VDC 
Speed: X:450mm/s, Y:300mm/s     
X motor: 0.6A/ two-phase,     Y motor: 0.8A/ two-phase 
Wire :4         Limit switches for X,Y installed

Comment: here are the specifications of the adafruit motor shield 
Adafruit Moto

•Up to 4 bi-directional DC motors with individual 8-bit speed selection (so, about 0.5% resolution)
•Up to 2 stepper motors (unipolar or bipolar) with single coil, double coil, interleaved or micro-stepping.
Features
• Power supply voltage: VM = 15 V(Max)
• Output current: IOUT = 1.2 A(ave)/3.2 A (peak)
• Output low ON resistor: 0.5Ω (upper+lower Typ. @ VM ≥ 5 V)

Comment: @matt links to both http://www.ebay.com/itm/New-XY-Stage-Table-With-Four-Slide-Bar-For-CO2-Laser-Machine-/252139117392?epid=1456511077&hash=item3ab4a99b50:g:JiYAAOSwwbdWKtts                                                                                                                                                                                       https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-motor-shield-v2-for-arduino

Comment: @denzelm2015: Can you put all the information you've sprinkled into your comments into your question and organise them in a coherent fashion. You're getting close votes already. It should have been obvious that you should put the links to datasheets of devices mentioned into your question.

Answer (score 1):

Since your motors require 24 volts and the power supply only puts out 15 volts, these will not work well together. Obtain a 24 volt supply/driver with at least a 1.5 amp output.